# how to write data from a point cloud file to a text file

Tags: python-3.x, io, point-clouds

I am trying to make a program that takes point cloud data and publishes the data into a txt file for some reason I am getting this error when I run my code:

```
File "readpts.py", line 14, in <module>
    f.write("%d    "%float(array[i][0].item()))
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

This should be a simple fix I just don't know what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d



pcd= o3d.io.read_point_cloud("cloud_cd.ply")
#print(pcd)
#print(np.asarray(pcd.points))
array=np.asarray(pcd.points)
f=open("cloud_cd.ply")
#print(type(float(array[0][0].item())))

for i in range(len(array)):
    f.write("%d    "%float(array[i][0].item()))
    f.write("%d    "%float(array[i][1].item()))
    f.write("%d    \n"%float(array[i][2].item()))
```

Answer (score 4):

You are opening your file in read mode which is the default one when using the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#open) function.

You should do something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d

pcd= o3d.io.read_point_cloud("cloud_cd.ply")
array=np.asarray(pcd.points)

with open("points.txt", mode='w') as f:  # I add the mode='w'
    for i in range(len(array)):
        f.write("%f    "%float(array[i][0].item()))
        f.write("%f    "%float(array[i][1].item()))
        f.write("%f    \n"%float(array[i][2].item()))
```

The `with` allows to close the file even if an error occured.

**Edit**

For the rounding issue, it is due to the %d. In order to have a float, replace the `%d` with `%f` (done in the code above). If you want to have only two decimals: `%.2f` (more information in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)).

If you are in python3.6+, you can use the [formatted string](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Comment: I think you meant to write :
with open("points.txt", mode='w') as f:

Comment: also it works now but it is rounding all the numbers off any way I could solve that issue?